# Python: JSON to CSV - special array handling

Tags: python, json, excel, rest, csv

I am using this JSON to CSV Converter to convert my JSON data to CSV, which I can further work on in Excel:
https://github.com/vinay20045/json-to-csv

The structure of my JSON data looks like following: https://pastebin.com/rPkqcXiF

```
{
  "page": 1,
  "pages": 1,
  "limit": 100,
  "total": 20,
  "items": [
    {...}
  ]
}
```

In line 64 there is an array of items. First item is shown from line 65 to 92.
The next array with the same content would then be started in line 93, when available.

My problem now is: I fetch 2 datasets from the REST API.
One of those datasets has an items array of 2 items. Then the python script will generate further columns for new items. First array is items_0, next is items_1 and so on.
Example where you can see that I mean, with formatting for view in Excel: Pastebin EqGHX07U  (only 2 links allowed here)

Instead of generating new columns when the amount of array elements rise, I'd like to have only one set of columns in the header of the csv. When the amount of array elements rise, there should be a new line generated with all other data like before - only the data of the new array changes.

Example where you can see that I mean, with formatting for view in Excel: Pastebin QLnaiqDs (only 2 links allowed here)

It would be awesome if you could help me out here! A few hints how to solve that are highly appreciated - I am not used to python though :(

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

If i understood correctly, here you have an approach. Think about it:

```
headers = []
csv_text = ""

def add_empty_fields():
    """Adds ';' char in each line in order to have empty fields for each new header"""
    csv_lines = csv_text.split("\n")
    csv_text = ""
    for line in csv_lines[:-1]:
        csv_text+=line+";\n"
    csv_text+=csv_lines[-1]


def add_ordered_data(json_parsed_to_dict):
    #Get headers of json
    tmp_list = set(json_parsed_to_dict.keys())
    #Add ordered data with headers list
    for h in headers:
        if h in tmp_list:
            tmp_list.discard(h)
            csv_text+=json_parsed_to_dict[h]+";"
        else:
            csv_text+=";"

    #Add new headers behind it 
    for new_header in tmp_list:
        headers.append(new_header)
        csv_text+=json_parsed_to_dict[h]+";"
        #add_empty_fields()
        """ You can do csv_lines.replace("\n",";\n") here instead of add_empty_fields hahah """

    csv_text+="\n"
```

I wrote all directly here, probably it have some fails but I hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

Apart from handling JSON data with `node` element. The script can also handle a JSON array **without** a `node` element as input. Refer [readme](https://github.com/vinay20045/json-to-csv/blob/master/README.md) file and [sample_2](https://github.com/vinay20045/json-to-csv/blob/master/samples/sample_2.json) in the repo.

So, you can pre-process the input, to get all the items from both the API and merge them before feeding the list to the converter. Like...

`data_to_be_processed = items_from_api_1 + items_from_api_2`

You could write this pre-processor as a standalone module or modify my script just after line 77.

Hope it helps...